# Array & Loop calculations

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a simple loan calculation of compound interest. When click "calculate", it will show in the list box the monthly payment every month and other information such as property tax. However, the information does not seem to appear at all.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal amount = 0.0m;
    double principal;
    double rate = 0.05;
    int Years;
    int timesPerYear = 12;

    Years = int.Parse(tbLoanTerm.Text); ;
    principal = int.Parse(tbAmount.Text);

    int Months = 0;
    decimal amountMonthly = 0.0m;

    listBox1.Items.Add("Month \t\t\tMonthly Payment\t\t\tProperty Tax");

    while(Months<=360)
    {
        Months = Years * 12;
        double body = 1 + (rate / timesPerYear);
        double exponent = timesPerYear * Years;
        amount = Convert.ToInt32(principal * Math.Pow(body, exponent));

        amountMonthly = amount / Months;

        propertytaxdec = amount * Property_Tax;

        listBox1.Items.Add(Months + "\t\t" + amountMonthly + "\t\t" + propertytaxdec);
        Months++;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add the programming language as a tag

Comment: What value is `Years`? Also, note that althought in your code you're incremeting `Months` in the end of the loop, you're overwriting it in the begining, and it's always the same value, as you're not changing `Years`.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms? Does the ListBox appear on the form editor? Has it been added correctly to your main page or form?

Comment: I will review my code. Thanks all i am a beginner only 3 weeks into this program..

Comment: Yeah, following on from what @Magnetron says, depending on the value of `Years`, your loop will either run exactly once (if `Years >= 30`) or forever (if `Years < 30`).  Your loop says (ignoring things that don't affect Months) `while (Month <= 360) { Months = Years * 12; Months++; }`